# ASP.NET Server Control - Thousands of Embedded Files?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols, servercontrol

I have created an ASP.NET Server Control and have it working just fine. However, I have decided that I now need to embed many, many images into the DLL rather than having them be required in local paths wherever the DLL is used.

To my horror I just discovered that doing this is a manual job where I have to go into hundreds of folders and subfolders and specify that I want those files to be embedded. I then have to change all of my markup to read these images and files via the WebResourceAttribute which is a chore to say the least.

My 2 questions:

1. Is there a quick way to embed hundreds of folders and subfolders worth of files with a few clicks?
2. If so, is there a way to simply reference these files as if they were on the file system? In other words, can I do a global search and replace for something like this:

   - Find:

     - script type="text/javascript" src="folder/
   - Replace With:

     - script type="text/javascript" src="{WebResourceStuff}/

Comment: Are your images included in the web project, or sitting in a separate folder system?

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming your images are already included in the web project, you might consider writing a Visual Studio macro to traverse your project folder structure and embed all the images.  If they aren't, you can still do the same thing by using the `System.IO.Directory` class.

   To get the right macro code to embed the image, turn the macro recording feature on and embed a couple of images.  That should cause the right macro code to be generated.  (Assuming this can be done with a macro, of course.)
2. Yes, you can definitely do this.  Try the Find in Files feature of VS and use the Replace option.